# Decrypt AES on server side c# encrypted on client side javascript using sjcl

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptography, sjcl

I am trying to decrypt some text encrypted client-side and having a difficult time making this happen.

I am using the Standford Javascript Crypto Library (sjcl) on client side which generates a json string that I can send to the server, something like this...

```
sjcl.encrypt("my_key", "something, something");
```

and produces this json string...

```
"{"iv":"tfyF7oMXjauOkRnwaffU3A==","v":1,"iter":10000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"bq5G63+hk0U=","ct":"KahF3hQ3FZZ2l7APxLB4nRvw03Xt/qD04AChoA=="}"
```

Now I receive this json string server-side, and tried to do this...

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my_key");

var iv = Convert.FromBase64String(data.iv.Value);
byte[] cypher = Convert.FromBase64String(data.ct.Value);
string plainText = null;

using (AesCryptoServiceProvider provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    provider.Key = key;
    provider.IV = iv;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = provider.CreateDecryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cypher))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
            {
                plainText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

return plainText;
```

The server side code above crashes on `plainText = sr.ReadToEnd;` and throws a "**The input data is not a complete block**". I know that AES requires the cypherText to have a block size of 128 and since the text varies in size, how do I guarantee that it has a block size of 128 and not screw up the intended value? Does setting the padding necessary here?

Also, what's the corresponding mode for "ccm" in the AESCryptoServiceProvider? Do the "iter" & "salt" need to be in play in order to decrypt correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Jaime

Comment: If this is to prevent someone sniffing the data in transit then given that my_key has already been sent over the wire it seems to be of of dubious utility.  SSL/TLS/HTTPS is the thing to use for transport security.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. Do I then send whatever message that I want encrypted via Headers? Assuming of course it's over SSL/TLS/HTTPS.

Comment: If you use https:// then everything between the client and the server is encrypted for you by the browser and web server automatically & transparently.

Comment: @AlexK. and I'll add "in a better way" since it doesn't require sending a private key in plaintext

Comment: @Alex... unfortunately, this is being sent via ajax and you can see in it in payload as clear as day even on https/ssl/tls

Comment: If it's https, it's encrypted. Even via ajax. If you're referring to seeing it in the browser developer tools, that doesn't mean it's not encrypted. That is just the browser making your life easier as a developer. Load up something like fiddler (without the HTTPS support enabled) or wireshark and you'll see it's encrypted.

Comment: Nope, if the Ajax is sending to `https://` then the data is encrypted.  (A browser dev toolkit will not show you the encrypted data)

Comment: Or if you are using a tool such as fiddler to look at the traffic then it has been configured to decrypt https traffic on the fly. (Something it can only do as its actually running on the host)

Comment: @Alex K.... it is the browser's developer tool, Chrome in particular. You can seem it on the request as the payload. Others can just launch the developer too and can see the payload. What am I missing here?

Comment: The above comment is for @dman2306 too.

Comment: That only works on the machine that is sending the request & thats fine as its your machine and its trusted - its where you enter the data before its encrypted after all.  The data the browser actually sends out over the network to the https address is always encrypted.

Comment: If you're goal is to hide something done on the client side from the client that is sending it, "you're doing it wrong." Even in your example, what prevents me from calling `sjcl.decrypt` in the developer tools and seeing the plain text? The purpose of encryption is to prevent some third party from listening in. The sender and receiver are allowed to know what the message is. If you don't want the sender to know what he is sending, I suggest you rethink your design a bit.

Comment: @dman2306.... great point and makes a lot of sense. Now how do I close this question since it is now moot?

Comment: @AlexK.Many thanks as well

Comment: SJCL uses CCM mode of operation by default, but C# doesn't provide this mode. Maybe BouncyCastle does.